# How to break a line of words after specific word using css or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a String, which I am displaying in one span.

```
<div>
 <span>The name of this person is john He is a cricket player </span>
</div>
```

here it is taking the width as of the text is . Now, I don't want to give any specific width to this element. So I tried

```
.parent{
  display: inline-block // so that the div should take only that width as of the text
}

.childspan {
  //word-wrap: break-all;
}
```

So, How do I break the span in two lines using CSS after specific word `is` ?

Is there any way to do this ? without giving the fixed width ?

Comment: Can you please try to use the `<br>` tag to enter line breaks.

Comment: Yes and also it doesn't look like you have tried to give a specific width to the div

Comment: Can you change the html?

Comment: There is no way in CSS to do it alone. You will need to manually change the mark up or have JavaScript change the mark up.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing with js would be

```
const child = document.querySelector('.parent .child');
child.innerHTML = child.innerHTML.replace("is", "is<br/>");
```

and it can be used in any element to break after word, also if you need to break after every is, then use it with RegExp

```
child.innerHTML = child.innerHTML.replace(/is/g, "is<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 `span` elements and add a `<br>` in between:

```html
<div>
 <span>The name of this person is john He is</span>
 <br>
 <span>a cricket player </span>
</div>
```

Or alternatively use the `::after` pseudo class:

```html
<div>
 <span id="line1">The name of this person is john He is</span>
 <span>a cricket player </span>
</div>

<style>
#line1::after{
    content: "\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use `<br>` tag, where u want to break a line.